# Is it possible for Flex to have a blended queue with Zendesk?

Tags: twilio, zendesk, twilio-flex

Is anyone aware of a way to combine handling Zendesk tickets with Twilio? The thought here is to have an agent work a ticket when they are idle on the phones, instead of having to have them manually change their status from "Available" to "Email". I was told this could possibly be done by using the Flex plugin and a few Task Router APIs. Wondering where to begin? I'm pretty new at Twilio development. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a few tutorials that may be of assistance to you:

- [Getting started with Twilio Flex YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT8uKoMYlqs)
- [What is Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/what-is-twilio-flex)
- [Twilio Flex: Core Concepts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/core-concepts/introduction)
- [How TaskRouter works](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/how-taskrouter-works)
- [Core Concepts: Routing in TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/core-concepts/routing)
- [Routing Part 2: Set Up Queues and Skills-based Routing](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/tutorials/queues-and-skills-based-routing)
- [Using Twilio TaskRouter with Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/routing)
- [Using TaskRouter with Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-taskrouter-twilio-flex)
- [Integrate Flex with Zendesk](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/integrations/zendesk)
- [Customize your Flex-Zendesk Integration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/integrations/zendesk/customize)
- [3 approaches for integrating your CRM into Twilio Flex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9ceipt591g)

These should help get you started <3

Answer (score 0):

Ciptex Race for Twilio Flex has an advanced zendesk integration which allows you to route tickets to agents automatically when they are not on the phone. You can also choose to embed Zendesk in Flex as an alternative Flex in Zendesk as well as integrate into multiple Zendesk domains from a single Flex project. https://showcase.twilio.com/partner-listing/a8E1W000000MKxgUAG